# Testing a Rails belongs_to model with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, model-view-controller, rspec

I have a `Profile` model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def fields_needed_for_completion
    [self.name, self.city]
  end

  def completed?
    !fields_needed_for_completion.any? { |f| f.nil? || f == "" }
  end
end
```

I am trying to determine how to write unit tests for a model with a `belongs_to` association.  In particular I'm not sure how to properly setup data for the tests.

So far, I've put together the following:

```
describe Profile do

  subject(:profile) { FactoryGirl.create(:profile) }

  describe "fields_needed_for_completion" do
    context "with all fields missing" do
      it "returns all fields as nil" do
        expect(profile.fields_needed_for_completion.all? &:blank?).to be true
      end
    end
  end

  describe "#completed?" do
    #TO DO
  end
end
```

Two questions:

1. Is it fine to use FactoryGirl to create the Profile object instead of calling `Profile.create` directly?  There are no attributes set in the factory right now (i.e., the factory is defined like so: `factory :profile do; end`)
2. As you can see, the `User` model is not used at all in these specs.  Is it appropriate to unit test a model in isolation like this, even though in practice it will belong to a user? Or should I somehow mock out the User?

Comment: unrelated question, but why are you reinventing ActiveModel validations in your Profile model there?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I see it:

1. Yes, it is fine, in fact - you're using `FactoryGirl` exactly as it is intended. Creating your test objects through factories (as opposed to explicitly calling `Model.create`) allows you to reuse creation logic between multiple tests and have all creation related logic in one place. 
   This means, for example, that if you'll add new a mandatory (one with validations) column to your model, then you'll have to adjust only the factory of that model instead of fixing numerous `Model.create` occurrences throughout your tests.
2. Your second question is methodological and not a technical so it's much more open to interpetation, but here's my two cents:
   I think it makes sense to test the `Profile` model both in isolation and in relation with the `User`. Non user related logic can be tested in isolation and user related logic can be tested in that context. 
   Note that `FactoryGirl` allows you to set up this context quite easily by defining a `User` [association](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#associations) in you `Profile` factory.